# Creating Water Ripples without Canvas?

Tags: javascript, ios, html, canvas, webgl

I need create a water ripple effect (client side only) that responds to touch. I have looked at various options and [found an interesting](http://code.almeros.com/code-examples/water-effect-canvas/#.URLyo1fnJLO) water ripple using canvas. I can replicate this without issue, however, it runs very slow. I have also looked at WebGL to create a similar water ripple effect but the effect I am going after must be able to run on an iPad and [according to Caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=webgl) WebGL is not supported by iOS.

My question is this: Is there a way to create water ripple effects that are quick and smooth without using canvas or WebGL (or flash). I am not against using canvas if there is a way to speed up the rendering. Again any code I use must run client side only and *must* work on an iPad.

Comment: openGL ES. It's the openGL implementation for iOS. EDIT: Actually, i'm guessing this is a webapp, and not a native app. In which case you cannot use openGL ES.

Comment: @Bergasms - Yes it will be a webapp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first question that may arise, if it's going to be used on a web platform or as a separate APP. Because at the moment iOS does not support WebGL natively. However there is a hack which permits to run on mobile browser. See this: http://vimeo.com/31553850. But i think this is out of scope if this will be a commercial product.

Secondly the canvas performance on mobile platform is not too good, but i found an experiment which i tested on iOS and it's quite satisfactory: http://media.chikuyonok.ru/ripple

Comment: This will be based and ran via the web through an iPad for commercial purposes. Thank You for the link, it looks interesting and I will check into it.